# Specific markers for 3D t-sne

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn

I have been trying to cram as much information into one 3D t-SNE figures I can. Thus, I'd like to add color to different points, and make different points different shape (genotype which is either 0,1, or 2 separated by color and test tube type which is either 1 or 0 separated by different figures/markers).

This is what I've tried, but it only works with the colors and all the points are star-shaped. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import seaborn as sns

metabolites = pd.read_excel("TPGx1_3_metabolitedata_withgender.xlsx")
df = pd.DataFrame(data=metabolites)
sub ='NIE.XXXXX'
sampleID = df['SampleID']
sampleID = sampleID.str.find(sub) 
df1 = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)


geno= df["geno"]

tsne = TSNE(n_components=3, perplexity=50, n_iter=5000, learning_rate=10, random_state=42).fit_transform(df1.T)
result = pd.DataFrame(data = tsne
             , columns = ['tsne0', 'tsne1', 'tsne2'])
result['geno'] = geno


marker={0:'*',-1:'^'}

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for l in np.unique(sampleID):
    ix=np.where(sampleID==0)
    ax.scatter(result['tsne0'], result['tsne1'], result['tsne2'], c=geno, marker = marker[0], cmap="Set2_r", s=60)

 
xAxisLine = ((min(result['tsne0']), max(result['tsne0'])), (0, 0), (0,0))
ax.plot(xAxisLine[0], xAxisLine[1], xAxisLine[2], 'r')
yAxisLine = ((0, 0), (min(result['tsne1']), max(result['tsne1'])), (0,0))
ax.plot(yAxisLine[0], yAxisLine[1], yAxisLine[2], 'r')
zAxisLine = ((0, 0), (0,0), (min(result['tsne2']), max(result['tsne2'])))
ax.plot(zAxisLine[0], zAxisLine[1], zAxisLine[2], 'r')
 
# label the axes
ax.set_xlabel("TSNE1")
ax.set_ylabel("TSNE2")
ax.set_zlabel("TSNE3")
ax.set_title("3D TSNE on the data set")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You are using custom data (which is fine to be private), but this is difficult to troubleshoot without a minimal example. Help us help you.

Comment: In your for loop. You are not using `l`. You are not using `ix` for that matter. Additionally, you're just setting `marker = marker[0]`. So I don't see where you're actually changing the marker type.

Answer (score 1):

I use the iris as an example, adding the same columns like yours:

```
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df["geno"] = pd.Categorical(df['species'])
df['geno'] = df.geno.cat.codes
df['sampleID'] = np.random.choice([0,1],len(df))

df.head()

    sepal_length    sepal_width petal_length    petal_width species geno    sampleID
0   5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa  0   1
1   4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 setosa  0   1
2   4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa  0   1
3   4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa  0   0
4   5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2 setosa  0   0
```

Perform tsne:

```
df1 = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df.iloc[:,:4])

tsne = TSNE(n_components=3, perplexity=50, n_iter=5000, learning_rate=10, random_state=42).fit_transform(df1)
result = pd.DataFrame(data = tsne,columns = ['tsne0', 'tsne1', 'tsne2'])
```

Then marker and geno, etc:

```
marker={0:'*',1:'^'}
sampleID = df['sampleID']
geno = df['geno']
```

In the plotting part, it is correct to subset on the samples to get the shapes, but you need to make sure to subset all the other variables as well:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for l in np.unique(sampleID):
    ix=np.where(sampleID==l)
    ax.scatter(result.iloc[ix]['tsne0'], result.iloc[ix]['tsne1'], result.iloc[ix]['tsne2'], 
               c = geno.loc[ix],marker = marker[l], cmap="Set2_r", s=60)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for extremely helpful and well explained answer!